# Return columns based on different conditions from same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given the following table, I'd like to be able to run a query that will return me two columns: one for mammals, and one for everything else.

```
id   class
---------
1    reptile
2    bird
3    mammal
4    mammal
5    mammal
```

Intended output:

```
mammal  others
--------------
3       1
4       2
5
```

I have tried the following (in addition to other strange things), but get a 'cannot repeat table name ... in from clause' error in MS Access:

```
SELECT a AS mammals, b AS others
FROM 
(SELECT id AS a FROM animals WHERE class = "mammal"), 
(SELECT id AS b FROM animals WHERE class <> "mammal");
```

Is this possible in SQL? Thanks!

Comment: Your expected output is non relational.  Can you explain the logic by which you arrived at your expected output?  This is something I might handle in the presentation layer.

Comment: The idea is that I'd like to be able to perform different further queries on the two different sets, depending on whether they fall into a target group. I can definitely do this if I make the two WHERE conditions separate queries, but I was hoping that there'd be a way to return the two groups in one query.

Comment: Access doesn't support row number, which could make this query a headache.  Still, give us the logic of the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by logic of the output.. Sorry :/ (not a big sql/access user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate `unique` numbers for both the queries `class='mammal'` and `class<>'mammal'` then use the unique number to join both queries. Since the number of records in `class='mammal'` and `class<>'mammal'` may vary we need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

but this is going to be a pain doing it in `Ms-Access` which does not support both `Row_Number` and `Full Outer Join`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT a.id, 
               a.class, 
               Count(*) AS Rn 
        FROM   animals a 
               INNER JOIN animals b 
                       ON a.id >= b.id 
        WHERE  b.class = 'mammal' 
        GROUP  BY a.id, 
                  a.class) a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id, 
                         a.class, 
                         Count(*) AS Rn 
                  FROM   animals a 
                         INNER JOIN animals b 
                                 ON a.id >= b.id 
                  WHERE  a.class <> 'mammal' 
                  GROUP  BY a.id, 
                            a.class) b 
              ON a.rn = b.rn 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT a.id, 
               a.class, 
               Count(*) AS Rn 
        FROM   animals a 
               INNER JOIN animals b 
                       ON a.id >= b.id 
        WHERE  b.class = 'mammal' 
        GROUP  BY a.id, 
                  a.class) a 
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT a.id, 
                          a.class, 
                          Count(*) AS Rn 
                   FROM   animals a 
                          INNER JOIN animals b 
                                  ON a.id >= b.id 
                   WHERE  a.class <> 'mammal' 
                   GROUP  BY a.id, 
                             a.class) b 
               ON a.rn = b.rn 
WHERE  a.rn IS NULL
```

**Note :** Am not very sure about Ms-Access syntax may be we need some pantheists around joins but this should give you an idea to start

Comment: I can't believe you actually did this +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Ha, Prdp needs a life! +1.

Comment: @Gustav - I don't think any developer has a life ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this may help

```
select id as Mammal , null as Others from table where class='mammal'
union
select null as Mammal , id as Others from table where class<>'mammal'
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected results.